# Reset loop after 4 times

Tags: php, css, loops

I am looping products on my page and the background-color goes as follow:
'transparent' - 'grey' - 'transparent' - 'grey'

There are 4 products on each row but when the second row starts it is doing the same order like:
***Situation 1 - Wrong situation***
'transparent' - 'grey' - 'transparent' - 'grey'
'transparent' - 'grey' - 'transparent' - 'grey'

But I want it like:
***Situation 2 - Correct situation***
'transparent' - 'grey' - 'transparent' - 'grey'
'grey' - 'transparent' - 'grey' - 'transparent'

Does anyone know how to edit my loop to get the structure as above?

```
<div class="row page-margin pb-5">
    <?php
    $term = get_field('product_category'); if( $term ): $cat = esc_html( $term->slug ); endif;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => $cat);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $product_id = get_the_id();
    $c = 0;
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 pl-0 pr-0">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="product-list-item <?php if ($c & 1) { ?>bg-grey<?php } ?>">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <?php echo $product->get_image('full', array('class' => 'img-fluid')); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <span class="product-title"><?php echo $product->get_name(); ?></span>
                        <span class="product-price">€ <?php $price = $product->price; $price_incl_tax = $price + round($price * ( 0 / 100 ), 2); $price_incl_tax = number_format($price_incl_tax, 2, ",", "."); $price = number_format($price, 2, ",", "."); echo $price_incl_tax; ?> incl. BTW</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php $c++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset ?>
</div>
```

Here is an image of the wrong situation (Situation 1):
[Wrong situation picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SFtp.png)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Use CSS `:nth-child()` selector to do this. Way more flexible. You can find the right `xn+y` value with a tool like [NTH-TEST](http://www.topdesignagencies.com/nth-test).

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Not sure if this would work as the flip order changes every alternate row.

Comment: @vivek_23 See my solution — it's not a simple selector to set up, but it's possible. Also, my link to NTH-TEST isn't great as it tests for a column layout, not rows, so I apologise for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to hardcode this into your template. Use CSS to achieve this with a slightly complex list of selectors. You can wrap this in a media query since I see you have `col-md-3`. Assuming you're using bootstrap, that would be `@include media-breakpoint-up(md)` you'd be using.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: gray;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}

.item:nth-child(4n+2):not(:nth-child(8n-2)), /* 2, 10, 18… */
.item:nth-child(4n+4):not(:nth-child(8n)), /* 4, 12, 20… */
.item:nth-child(4n+1):not(:nth-child(8n+1)), /* 5, 13, 21… */
.item:nth-child(4n+3):not(:nth-child(8n+3)) { /* 7, 15, 23… */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
  <div class="item">18</div>
  <div class="item">19</div>
  <div class="item">20</div>
</div>
```

Now to explain the selector logic: you want to target every 2nd and 4th child on odd rows, and the 1st and 3rd child on even rows. To do so, you target, respectively:

- Every 2 items that aren't a multiple of 6
- Every 4 items that aren't a multiple of 8
- Every 5 items that aren't a multiple of 9
- Every 7 items that aren't a multiple of 11

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this works then I'll upvote it. Not good enough on css to know or test it. But just ping me if OP accepts it or says it works. Nice answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a little tricky because you are changing the order of decision at the chunk of 4.
To decide this, you can have an extra `$flag` variable which is initially set to `false`.

So, the check goes as:

```
if ($flag && ($c & 1) == 0 || !$flag && ($c & 1) == 1)
```

This says if we are at the odd iteration(when $flag is false) and current `$c` is odd or we at the even iteration(when $flag is true) and current `$c` is even.

We reset the flag when `$c` gets reinitialized to `0` indicating next row flip.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$c = 0;
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 pl-0 pr-0">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="product-list-item <?php if ($flag && ($c & 1) == 0 || !$flag && ($c & 1) == 1) { ?>bg-grey<?php } ?>">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <?php echo $product->get_image('full', array('class' => 'img-fluid')); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <span class="product-title"><?php echo $product->get_name(); ?></span>
                        <span class="product-price">€ <?php $price = $product->price; $price_incl_tax = $price + round($price * ( 0 / 100 ), 2); $price_incl_tax = number_format($price_incl_tax, 2, ",", "."); $price = number_format($price, 2, ",", "."); echo $price_incl_tax; ?> incl. BTW</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php $c = ($c + 1) % 4; $flag = $c == 0 ? !$flag : $flag; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it done in php the method I found working is to use two arrays which is out of sync with transparent and grey.
Then echo from one array on one row then switch.

It's not a nice code but it does the trick.

```
$arr1 = ['transparent', 'grey', 'transparent', 'grey'];
$arr2 = ['grey', 'transparent', 'grey', 'transparent'];


$i = 0;
$bool = true;
Your loop{
    if($bool){
        echo 'color ' . $arr1[$i] . "\n";
    }else{
        echo 'color ' . $arr2[$i] . "\n";
    }
    $i = ++$i % 4;
    if($i ==0) $bool = !$bool;
}
```

Here is a running example of the code:

https://3v4l.org/XdcHB